# Image multi classification - filter unqualified building photos from qualified ones

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, classification

For a building photo dataset, I want to train models to filter unqualified photos, such as `incomplete (in which only part of buildings are taken in case I want full scale of building photos), skewed (the buidlings taken in the photos have a severe slope), overexposed (because of sunlight), blurred, dim (lack of sunlight)`, etc. from normal and qualified photos, I'm using image multi-classification method, does that look like a correct direction to deal with this problem?

I suppose it may have good result on filteration of some of unqualified such as `blurred, dim` images, because those have some common characteristics and paterns which easy to detect for deep learning algorithms, but for others such as`incomplete and skewed building` photos, I want to get confirm if using images classification is right solution? Are there any better ways to do that?

Thanks for your comments and reponse at advance.

Comment: You have an interesting problem. But your question may be too open ended for this forum and asking for opinions. Please review the help section for what are appropriate questions and how to ask a good question for this forum.

Comment: Sorry for my unspecified question, just fan of stackoverflow community. ;)